# The _UNICODE definition exists in linux in c?

Tags: c, linux, unix

Does the `_UNICODE` definition exist in linux C?

If it doesn't exist, is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

The core libraries in a GNU/Linux system do not support Microsoft-style ANSI/Unicode switching. There is nothing like the `TCHAR` type which goes to `CHAR` or `WCHAR`.

If you want wide characters, you explicitly use `wchar_t` and functions which use it.

There is a widespread practice of continuing to use `char` strings, but with UTF-8 encoding.

Internationalized programs either do that or use `wchar_t` or some mixture of the two.

Comment: @Gusteivosgp Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what you can do instead of writing thank you comments when someone answers your question.

Comment: Note that if you are porting an existing Windows program that uses UTF-16 internally, you should **not** convert it to use of `wchar_t`, as there is no guarantee of this being any particular encoding (officially it depends on the locale; in practice I _think_ glibc always uses UTF-32 but that's not contractual).  In plain ISO C, the best alternative is [`uchar.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte) and [`char16_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/char16_t) strings.  [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/) may be more congenial, but it's a third party library.

Comment: @zwol Also, don't use `char` because the encoding might be EBCDIC and not ASCII/UTF-8.

Comment: @Kaz You say that like you're being sarcastic, but I have in fact written code that had to care about that.